# Easiest way to check if property is null or empty in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method which checks some properties (not all) of Account and if any of these properties is null or empty it returns true, I need a elegant way of doing this without having to write so many conditional statements.

```
private boolean isInvalidSlateAccount(Account account) {

    return (account.getAccesskeyid() == null || account.getAccesskeyid().trim().isEmpty()
            || account.getAccount() == null || account.getAccount().trim().isEmpty()
            || account.getAwsregion() == null || account.getAwsregion().trim().isEmpty()
            || account.getGatewayname() == null || account.getGatewayname().trim().isEmpty()
            || account.getGatewaytype() == null || account.getGatewaytype().trim().isEmpty()
            || account.getSecretaccesskey() == null || account.getSecretaccesskey().trim().isEmpty()
            || account.getTenant() == null || account.getTenant().trim().isEmpty() || account.getZone() == null || account
            .getZone().trim().isEmpty());

}
```

I have done this

```
private boolean isInvalidSlateAccount(Account account) {
    List<String> properties = Arrays.asList(
        account.getAccesskeyid(),
        account.getAccount(),
        account.getAwsregion(),
        account.getGatewayname(),
        account.getGatewaytype(),
        account.getSecretaccesskey(),
        account.getTenant(),
        account.getZone()
    );
    return properties.stream()
        .anyMatch(s -> (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()));

}
```

But this will check the condition for all properties of my Account object which I don't intend to do. How can this be achieved more elegantly?

Comment: *But this will check the condition for all properties*, not really, it depends on how you initialize properties list.

Comment: *But this will check the condition for all properties of my Account object* - you have shown the opposite yourself, via `List<String> properties = Arrays.asList....`

Comment: as a side note you should use directly `Stream.of(...)` instead of `Arrays.asList(...).stream()`

Comment: @Adrian right, but usually you would provide a method like `static boolean nonNullOrEmpty(String ... values)`, so I guess that stems from that in OP's example

Comment: Write a method `isNullOrEmpty(String)`, so you can invoke `return isNullOrEmpty(account.getAccesskeyid()) || isNullOrEmpty(account.getAccount())` etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner Preferrably the design proposed by Eugene works better here(opinion though unless countered by facts).

Comment: The Stream solution does exactly the same as the first variant. You could improve it by using `Stream.of`, as @Adrian, but regardless of that, it’s not clear what your problem is.

Comment: This is nonsense. The Stream processes its own elements, i.e. those from the list, and nothing else. What magic should make the Stream even know those “all properties of Account object”? The Stream doesn’t know that an Account object exists. All it knows, are the strings from the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a method `isNullOrEmpty(String)`:

```
static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
  return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()
  // Or return s == null || s.isBlank(); in Java 11+
}
```

So you can write:

```
return isNullOrEmpty(account.getAccesskeyid())
    || isNullOrEmpty(account.getAccount())
    /* etc */;
```

I consider this preferable to doing something that involves constructing streams or lists, because it's just *simple*: it's using very basic language features that are easily understandable by even a novice programmer.

In addition, it avoids evaluating all of the fields (e.g. passing `String... ss` to `isNullOrEmpty`, and then doing something on the array) because it short-circuits, in that it will stop as soon as it finds the first null or empty string.

It also does not require creation of any objects (like the implicit array, or a `List` in the case of `Arrays.asList(...)`) that are simply artefacts of invoking the method: `trim()` does potentially create objects, but this is "useful" work, insofar as this is necessary to evaluate the condition.

Comment: but that is such a small price to pay in exchange for readability IMO... we have the same approach in our code base and it's actually `static boolean nonNullOrEmpty(String first, String ... rest) {....}`

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, strictly speaking, you're still potentially creating a new object: `trim()` returns a new String instance if the source string starts or ends with whitespace.

Comment: Minor note: `s.trim().isEmpty()` could be replaced by `s.isBlank()` (java 11).

Comment: Seriously, short-circuiting when an object is *invalid*, is the least thing, I’d care about. Same for a trivial temporary object. The probably most expensive operation is `trim()`, which could be avoided, if that method ever becomes performance relevant.

Comment: @Zabuza thanks, edited. I would mention, though, that there is a slight semantic difference, in that `trim()` does not remove all leading/trailing whitespace characters (only those with codepoints < 32).

Comment: I had done this but see my issue here is I am reducing conditional statements from 15 to 7 but my sonar report says that max conditional statement allowed is 3 , Thats why I was looking for a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: @PrashantRaghav don't let the tail wag the dog. If you have to check 7 things, you have to check 7 things.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a classic use case for JSR 380 the standard Java Bean Validation framework.

It allows you to add `@NotNull` annotations to your fields in the Account class. You could then do something like the following:

```java
@NotNull
private String awsRegion;
```

```java
Account account = new Account();
account.setAwsRegion(null)

Set<ConstraintViolation<Account>> violations = validator.validate(Account);
```

You would need to add the validation API as dependency, plus a validator implementation, such as the Hibernate reference implementation:

```xml
<!-- Java eXtensions for Validation API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Java eXtensions for Unified Expression Language API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate Validator as implementation of the JSR 349 Bean Validation Specification -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a link to get you started:
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation